# GetMethod equivalent in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net-standard

In `.NET Framework` you can easily reflect methods. E.g.:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(object).GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", bindingFlags);
```

In a `.NET Standard` project, however, the compiler complains:

> error CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetMethod' and
>   no extension method 'GetMethod' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

**Q:** How do you perform equivalent reflection using `.NET Standard`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For almost *all* reflection in .NET Core 1.x, you need a `TypeInfo` instead of `Type`.

There's an extension method of `GetTypeInfo` in the `System.Reflection` namespace, so you want:

```
using System.Reflection; // For GetTypeInfo
...
var methodInfo = typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", bindingFlags);
```

Note that [`TypeInfo.GetMethod()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.getmethod?view=netstandard-1.6) doesn't exist .NET Standard earlier than 1.6, but [`TypeInfo.DeclaredMethods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.declaredmethods) has been in since 1.0.

.NET Standard 2.0 reintroduced members into `System.Type` (as part of reinstating a large portion of the desktop framework into .NET Standard) so you don't need to go through this hoop when targeting 2.0+.

Comment: Worth noting that in .NET Standard 2.0 you can just do `typeof(object).GetMethod`

Comment: @Evk: Yup, will note that.

Comment: It seems VS 2017.4 ships with 1.6.

Comment: @l33t: It's not a matter of what VS ships with - you should be deliberately choosing which version you want *your project* to target. That will entirely depend on who's going to use that project.